# Image not displayed on Array of Images

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiimageview

here the issue is i'm getting a array of images from server ,but i'm not able to displayed image on `ImageView`.Below code ,

```
 for (int i=0; i<=images.count; i++) {

           images= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",  nil];

           [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:i]]];

   }
```

Can you please help how can i display image.Thanks.

Comment: Where the images are stored? and imageView is one or many?

Comment: are you storing images?

Comment: Only one imageView and i'm getting the array of images from server side @the_UB

Comment: you want to show all images on single imageview?!! and are you using tableview or collectionview?

Comment: yes i want show all images on Single ImageView & i'm using imageView on the ScrollView like image Slide Show

Comment: Check my edited answer. You question is divided into two parts.

Comment: where are you storing the images? This only work if the images is stored in the bundle. If the images is present in server first you would need to get the exact url of the image from the server and then use the following code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this and see what happens:

```
images= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",@"logo.png",  nil];

for (int i=0; i<=images.count; i++) {
       [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

**Edit:**

Firstly, the code you are using will not display any image since all images are stored at server side. To retrieve these images you need to [Get image through url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528244/how-to-display-image-on-uiimageview-using-url-and-nsstring-in-ios).

Secondly, to show image in slider you have to use [Page View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709555/how-to-create-an-image-slide-show-using-pageview-controller-in-iphone) or check this link:[How to create image slider in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220071/how-to-create-image-slider-in-ios).

Answer (score 0):

where are you storing the images? This only work if the images is stored in the bundle. If the images is present in server first you would need to get the exact url of the image from the server(for example it would be similar to http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg) and then use the following code

```
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[images objectAtIndex:i]]]];
```